# django non-rel / Managing per-field indexes on App Engine

Tags: python, django, django-nonrel

I'm trying to move my gae webapp project to django non-rel. I'm pretty new to Python and Django (non-rel). Right now I'm setting up the admin backend.

When I want to look at the history of a model entry I encounter this problem:

```
Caught DatabaseError while rendering: TextField is not indexed, 
by default, so you can't filter on it. Please add an index definition
for the column object_id on the model django.contrib.admin.models.LogEntry
as described here: http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/2010/07/Managing-per-field-indexes-on-App-Engine
```

I followed the advice on the give site, but the problem persists.

My gae_models_settings.py looks like this:

```
from maps.models import Poll, Choice
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry

FIELD_INDEXES = {
    Poll: {'indexed': ['question']},
    Choice: {'indexed': ['choice']},
    LogEntry: {'indexed': ['object_id']},
```

}

And in my settings.py I added:

```
GAE_SETTINGS_MODULE = (
    'maps.gae_models_settings',
)
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a letter missing in '[GAE_SETTINGS_MODULE](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/2010/07/Managing-per-field-indexes-on-App-Engine)'.

The correct version is :

```
GAE_SETTINGS_MODULES = (
    'maps.gae_models_settings',
)
```

Answer (score 2):

if you put ae_models_settings.py in the same level as settings.py, I think it should be:

```
GAE_SETTINGS_MODULES = (
'gae_models_settings',
)
```

works for me.